# Rate limit "heavy" HTTP requests in Nginx

Tags: nginx

The task: to limit certain requests ("heavy", incurring large resource usage) in Nginx, while applying less restrictive limits on other requests.

Current configuration looks like this:

```
http {
    ...
    # Up to 2/min for /heavy/request
    limit_req_zone $remote_addr zone=slow:10m rate=2r/m;
    # Up to 60/sec for everything else
    limit_req_zone $remote_addr zone=common_sec:10m rate=60r/s;

    server {
        ...
        limit_req zone=common_sec burst=90 nodelay;

        location /heavy/request {
            limit_req zone=slow;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I was expecting that /heavy/request will be blocked if attempted more than twice a minute, but that limit seems to never to be applied.

How should I modify the configuration to restrict the "heavy" request as intended?

Thanks.

Comment: You should show complete server block. My wild guess — this location does internal redirect or never matched